# getting the nearest coordinates from a static JSON file using a latitude and longitude as the input

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing .net core Web API for returning the approximately matched latitude and longitude values from static JSON file which contains list of static data, based on the user input latitude and longitude values.

But I am struggling for to get the approximately matched latitude and longitude values from static JSON file based on user input values.

This is Model structure in the database:

```
    public class Location    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me is there any algorithm for solving above problem?

Comment: What do you mean by approximately matched latitude and longitude? The nearest coordinates? Are you using entity framework? What is your database system? SQL Server or other?

Comment: For example, Whenever user enter latitude value as `12.971599` and longitude value as `77.594566` then I want the nearest results based on my database records.

Comment: Ok, and what is your database system, and how do you plan to make the query, using ADO.NET and SQL or Entity Framework or any other ORM? Also, how are your coordinates stored in your database, i.e. using numeric values, a geometry column, etc...

Comment: @Isma, Right now I am using static json file which contains list of locations data like `      "Name": "Location-01",
      "Address": "Village-01",
      "Latitude": 44.968046,
      "Longitude": 94.420307,
      "Pincode": 460059,
      "ContactNumber": "+91-XX-XXXX-XXXX"  `. But in future I am planning to use Azure SQL Database.

Comment: ok, so you should clarify your question with all this info... but the method to retrieve data will likely be completely different from one system to the other.

Comment: @Isma, Please look at my updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189601/discussion-between-pradeep-and-isma).